# Google Data Studio bar chart comparing multiple metrics as % of the total

Tags: looker-studio

Let's say I have 10 companies that have signed up to my service, and then dropped off. I want to figure out how many of these companies are hitting milestones of usage in my system, so I want a bar chart that shows the data. For instance, I have 2 boolean fields on the companies, "Added Card Details" and "Logged in 3 times".

How do I create a bar chart which shows 2 bars, the % of companies which have that value set to "true", as the example below?

I'm pulling the data from BigQuery, but here's an example table of data to create the graph from:

| Name | Added Card Details | Logged in 3 times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Com1 | true | true |
| Com2 | true | true |
| Com3 | false | true |
| Com4 | false | true |
| Com5 | false | false |
| Com6 | false | false |
| Com7 | false | false |
| Com8 | false | false |
| Com9 | false | false |
| Com10 | false | false |

Should produce a graph which looks like:

[image: Example graph]

Here's a sheet with example data and an example graph:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12jt1ZlhJ-5Hc8XtQsyXVVnLC1F6GOZz9euZkN2y1jNw/edit?usp=sharing

Here's my attempt at creating the graph. Not sure where to go from here when Dimension has to be declared and only allows one option.

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f9a2db1c-2c32-41b6-8e47-1848e2577417

Answer (score -5):

One approach is to use a [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) field as the dimension and 2 [calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in each of the metrics:

| Description | Details |
| --- | --- |
| **Chart**: | [Column Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7165560) |
| **Dimension 1**: **Formula**: | Actions `"Actions"` |
| **Metric 1**: **Formula**: **Type**: | Added Card Details `COUNT(IF(Added Card Details = "TRUE", Added Card Details, NULL)) / COUNT(Name)` Number > Percent |
| **Metric 2**: **Formula**: **Type**: | Logged in 3 times `COUNT(IF(Logged in 3 times = "TRUE", Logged in 3 times, NULL)) / COUNT(Name)` Number > Percent |

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/98f5ac97-e4ff-473d-9ab4-3d46554ab924) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vy5JZ-U0prAjTTy-C6yKH9__kOkl5gCyu20KNF2ivB0/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and an image elaborate:

[image: chart]

Comment: Ahhh I see, that's really interesting and makes sense as the approach. I won't mark anything as answered yet but thanks so much, I'll be able to mess around with my figures this weekend now. Data studio is amazingly powerful.

Comment: Nimantha do you have an update on this? Else I'll mark your solution as the right one, but this feels a bit janky to use so want to know if there's a better way

Comment: Haven't got around to it... Though in any case, it would be a separate answer, as it's a different approach.